# Bipolar stepper motor sequence, wiring and dual h bridge

Tags: stepper-motor, h-bridge, parallel-port

Im facing some issues to figure out sequence of my bipolar(specifically) and unipolar stepper motor. However , I've managed to get Dual H Bridge but couldn't find out the example/documentation for the one i got.

I want to drive my bipolar stepper motor via dual h bridge using parallel port and unipolar via IC UN2003.

You're expert guidennce for pulse sequence and wiring identification will be truly appriciable. Thanks!!

Pictures

DUAL H BRIDGE : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLruy.jpg

Stepper Motors scavenged from printers : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN15A.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do improve the answer if you can as i really dont know much electronics .

However, I'm able to understand and get very good explanations and documentation from of-course THE WEB.

**STEPPER MOTOR WIRING AND SEQUENCE**
 WIRE TRACING WITH MULTIMETER
  This tutorial helped to trace coil/wiring using multimeter (that stupid to not even determine coil)
  http:// 42bots .com /tutorials/stepper-motor-wiring-how-to/ (remove space)

STEPPING SEQUENCE
 This very good demonstration helped alot to figuring out pulse sequence.
  http:// www. youtube .com/watch?v=kAyDmovM18E (remove space)

**DUAL H BRIDGE**
helpful documentation
https:// www. bananarobotics .com/shop/How-to-use-the-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-Motor-Driver  (remove space)

**PARALLEL PORT**
Once i understand the above mentioned and able to create logic i use I/O in c/c++     `outb();`     to interface stepper motor.

*I need to study more to get control of speed and torque*

Comment: It's good you got it sorted out but answers are supposed to be useful for others in the future. Maybe you could add some more details or a schematic of your working solution?

Comment: I will for sure later when i get free from work. Ive gone through alot to get simple answer

Comment: Tell us what you've read, and what experiments proved to be insightful.

Comment: Hope i tried as you might expected..thanks anyway.